# How do I get a country as a region?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I am trying to color a country map based on level of weather risk in each admin area. I believe this can best be done in R, though my knowledge of R is next to zero.

From this post [cannot add labels for country with ggplot, geom_polygon and geom_text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76121544/cannot-add-labels-for-country-with-ggplot-geom-polygon-and-geom-textlibrary(maptools)), I have been able to run the code and plot a risk map of all countries in Africa. I tried to adapt the code for my purpose as below:

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

all_districts <- data.frame(region = c("Maseru",
"Butha-Buthe",
"Leribe",
"Berea",
"Mafeteng", 
"Mohale's Hoek", 
"Quthing",
"Qacha's Nek",
"Mokhotlong",
"Thaba-Tseka"),                          
risk = c(4, 4, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2))

table(all_districts$risk)
mapdata_x <- map_data('world') %>% filter(region %in% all_districts$region)
mapdata_x <- mapdata_x %>% left_join(all_districts, by='region')
label_data <- mapdata_x %>% group_by(region) %>% filter(row_number() == 1)

ggplot(mapdata_x, aes (x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
geom_polygon(aes(fill = factor(risk)), linewidth = 0.25, color = "black") +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("#a6d96a", "#ffffbf", "#fdae61", "#d7191c"),
name = "Risk Level") +
theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
axis.text.y = element_blank(),
axis.ticks = element_blank(),
axis.ticks = element_blank(),
axis.title.y = element_blank(),
axis.title.x = element_blank(),
rect = element_blank())+
labs(title = "Weather Risk Levels") +
geom_label_repel(data = label_data,
aes(x = long, y = lat, label = region), size = 3,
max.overlaps = 12)
```

My code fails on the line

```
mapdata_x <- map_data('world') %>% filter(region %in% all_districts$region)
```

Giving the error:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function '%in%': object 'region' not found.
```

How do I define this so that I can get Lesotho as a region?, or if there is an alternative way of achieving this.

Comment: It works for me, except that the regions you defined within `all_districts` don't exist. Are those countries or what?

Comment: These are districts within Lesotho. How would one get districts within a country, how to incorporate a shapefile?

Comment: The `map_data` function pulls data from the `maps` package. That package has a limited number of dataset available. You'll have to find some online source for the map data you desire. But Stack Overflow is for asking specific programming questions, not for asking for the locations of particular map data. Maybe try a site like [opendata.se] or [gis.se] instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(sf); library(sp)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2); library(ggrepel)

download.file("https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/diva/adm/LSO_adm.zip",
              "LSO_adm.zip")
unzip("LSO_adm.zip", exdir= "LSO_adm")

mapdata_x <- st_read(dsn="LSO_adm\\LSO_adm1.shp", quiet = TRUE)
all_districts <- data.frame(region = c("Maseru", "Butha-Buthe",
                                       "Leribe", "Berea", 
                                       "Mafeteng", "Mohale's Hoek", 
                                        "Quthing", "Qacha's Nek", 
                                        "Mokhotlong", "Thaba-Tseka"),
                            risk = c(4, 4, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2))

mapdata_x <- mapdata_x %>% left_join(all_districts, by = c("NAME_1" = 'region'))
label_data <-  suppressWarnings(st_centroid(mapdata_x)) %>% 
                bind_cols(., st_coordinates(.))

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = mapdata_x, aes(fill = factor(risk))) +
  geom_label_repel(data = label_data, aes(x = X, y = Y, label = NAME_1), 
                   size = 3, max.overlaps = 12) +
  labs(title = "Weather Risk Levels") +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Risk Level", 
                    values = c("#a6d96a", "#ffffbf", "#fdae61", "#d7191c")) +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        rect = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>